# SQL Server R2: select statement with where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to select some data with the where clause for the following table.

**Example**:

```
create table test
(
  pid int,
  pname varchar(10)
)
```

Inserting some data:

```
insert into test values(1,'Active');
insert into test values(1,'DeActive');
insert into test values(2,'Active');
insert into test values(2,'DeActive');
insert into test values(3,'Active');
insert into test values(3,'Active');
insert into test values(4,'Active');
insert into test values(5,'DeActive');
```

Now I want to show the data from test where the process id that is `pid` has both process names that is `Active` and `DeActive`.

**Expected Result**:

```
pid  
----
1  
2
```

**Note**: The above process id `pid` 1 and 2 are having both process name `pname`  that is `Active` and `DeActive`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Intersect to get the common pid values, check the below query:

```
Select Distinct pid From Test Where 
pname ='Active' 
Intersect 
Select Distinct pid From Test Where 
pname = 'DeActive'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   select distinct a.pid 
   from test a 
   join test b on a.pname=b.pname 
   where a.pname not in('Deactive') and a.pid < 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.pid 
from test a
join test d on a.pid = d.pid and d.pname = 'DeActive'
where a.pname = 'Active'
```

Comment: I added the a., although it could be b. as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is without any hard coded value and can edit the number '1' for future `pnames`

```
select distinct pid from (select pid,count(distinct pname) as cnt 
from test
group by pid) tab
where cnt>1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    a.pid 
FROM 
    dbo.test a
join 
    dbo.test b on a.pid = b.pid 
    and a.pname = 'Active' and b.pname = 'DeActive'
```

Comment: add some explanations!

Comment: It is a self join on table test to achieve what would otherwise have been two tables. Think of it in this way if you had one table T1 as (pid,'activate) and second table T2 as (pid,'deactivate'). Then almost anyone would do T1 JOIN T2 ON predicate of pid. In the above query the alias 'a' and alias 'b' represent this same relation.

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```
Select Pid from 
(
select pid , Count (distinct pname) as Pnamecount from test as a
group by pid 
having COUNT(*) > 1
) as temp
Where temp.Pnamecount != 1
```